# Year validation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, dom-events

I want to do year validation whre it should be only numeric and Its should be 4 digit long and between 1920 to current year for that I have create Javascript function as follows:

```
function yearValidation(year) {
    var text = /^[0-9]+$/;
    if (year != 0) {
        if ((year != "") && (!text.test(year))) {

            alert("Please Enter Numeric Values Only");
            return false;
        }

        if (year.length != 4) {
            alert("Year is not proper. Please check");
            return false;
        }
        var current_year=new Date().getFullYear();
        if((year < 1920) || (year > current_year))
            {
            alert("Year should be in range 1920 to current year");
            return false;
            }
        return true;
    }
```

and called it on `onkeypress="return yearValidation(this.value)"`

But when I enter `1` it gives me alert:

> Year should be in range 1920 to current year

Comment: Well, `1` it's not empty, it's not 4, and it's less than `1920` so it's seems correct.

Comment: Do it `onchange` instead of `onkeypress`.

Comment: do it `onBlur` of your text input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Applying two event should solve the problem.
HTML:

```
    <input type="text" 
        onblur="yearValidation(this.value,event)" 
        onkeypress="yearValidation(this.value,event)"
    >
```

JS:

```
function yearValidation(year,ev) {

  var text = /^[0-9]+$/;
  if(ev.type=="blur" || year.length==4 && ev.keyCode!=8 && ev.keyCode!=46) {
    if (year != 0) {
        if ((year != "") && (!text.test(year))) {

            alert("Please Enter Numeric Values Only");
            return false;
        }

        if (year.length != 4) {
            alert("Year is not proper. Please check");
            return false;
        }
        var current_year=new Date().getFullYear();
        if((year < 1920) || (year > current_year))
            {
            alert("Year should be in range 1920 to current year");
            return false;
            }
        return true;
    } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess it's:

```
 if (year.length < 4) {
```

not

```
if (year.length != 4) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Or directly in form

```
<input name="date_check" 
type="text" 
title="Date must be in this case:dd.mm.yy" 
pattern="^[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{2}$" />
```